# Scrolling images with ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

Using the following XML and java code I add images taken with camera to LinearLayout within a ScrollView.

XML:

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/detailsback"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/imageSlider"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Java (runs in Fragment):

```
private void setTakePicButton(){
    mTakePicButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mBitmap = mTextureView.getBitmap();
                Date currentDateTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                String filename = getFileName();
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

                try {
                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream( filename);
                    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);// bmp is your Bitmap instance

                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

                    linearLayout.addView(imageView);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                }
       }
    });
}
```

Problem is whenever I add a pic to linearLayout (id:imageSlider) it is added with large margins like shows in the picture

[image: after adding the first pic]

[image: enter adding the second pic]

I want the images to show in a sequence like in the following pic.
[image]

Comment: so what is your expected result? you prefer to have the picture that display fully in the `linear layout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that the image in the bottom is centered instead of outlined to the left? This might be caused by the `wrap_content` width for the linear layout.

I would also suggest you to use some sort of a list view instead of a `LinearLayout` and adding items manually. A `RecyclerView` would be a nice solution and is able to be set to horizontal as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 01**

You can set the image to bounds using `FIT_XY` scale type

```
imgview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

You can find all the `ScaleTypes` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType)

**Solution 02**

If you are trying to view images like a list you can use a `RecyclerView`:
[Create a List with RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

**Solution 03**

If you want to display the images side by side, Set `layout_weight` to `imageView`

This is how to do that programmatically, (The Last param is the weight )

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    1.0f
);
imageView.setLayoutParams(param);
```

Comment: setScaleType stretch the image...., what I meant is I want the image to show as in the picture and eliminate the margins on the sides.

Comment: Use a `RecycleView`. it will be much easy and suitable for your scenario.

Comment: Same thing with Recycleview. Each pic I add to the Recycleview shows with margins to sides, Image width and height is set to `wrap_content` and still it looks like the last pic in the original post.

Comment: See the updated answer. But I never tried it with a `ScrollView`

Comment: I tried it with both width,  `MATCH_PARENT` and `WRAP_CONTENT` and still got the same results. When setting the width to specific value (e.g. 100) it display the images side by side.